# How can I do this in prolog without causing an infinite loop?

Tags: prolog, infinite-loop

I want to do something like this in Prolog:

```
some_commutative_property(X,Y) :- some_commutative_property(Y,X).
some_commutative_property(1,2).
some_commutative_property(3,4).
```

such that querying both `some_commutative_property(1,2).` and `some_commutative_property(2,1).` returns true.

The problem is obviously that the first line creates an infinite loop. How can I get around this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There may be multiple solutions:

- Split the predicate in two:

  `some_commutative_property(X,Y) :- some_commutative_property_aux(X,Y).`
  `some_commutative_property(X,Y) :- some_commutative_property_aux(Y,X).`

with `some_commutative_property_aux(1,2).` and `some_commutative_property_aux(3,4).`

- Enforce the order:

  `some_commutative_property(X,Y) :- X>Y, some_commutative_property(Y,X).`

with `some_commutative_property_aux(1,2).` and `some_commutative_property_aux(3,4).` This will work only under assumption that the basic facts are only of the form `some_commutative_property(A,B)` with `A =< B`.

- If you do not like these solutione you might use a memoization mechanism known as tabling. By far not all Prolog dialects support tabling, XSB, for instance, does. As David S. Warren explains "[The idea is very simple: never make the same procedure call twice: the first time a call is made, remember all the answers it returns, and if it's ever made again, use those previously computed answers to satisfy the later request. In XSB the programmer indicates what calls should be tabled by using a compiler directive"](http://www.cs.sunysb.edu/~warren/xsbbook/node14.html). Adding `:- table some_commutative_property/2` to your original code will also save the problem.

Comment: I thought about that but I would prefer not to unless that is the last option.

Comment: I have updated my answer with an alternative solution using tabling.